# The background of Michonne's walker drones

Tags: plot-explanation, the-walking-dead

Does anyone know the true background of the walker drones that Michonne slaughtered before she and Andrea were taken to Woodbury in *The Walking Dead*?

So far, all I have been able to determine is that, whoever these walkers were, Michonne knew them -- they had betrayed her in some way (possible abuse, assault or attack) -- and has been quoted as saying that they deserved it...

Does anyone have any clues, possibly from the comic books?

Comment: I'm pretty sure this hasn't been answered inside of the WD TV series universe, and as we've seen so many times before, many things from the comic book universe does not play over to what we see on screen. It is probably just conjecture or speculation at this point. If someone has an answer, I'm game, no doubt, but it may not hold true for the series.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It was her boyfriend and a friend of his. It was mentioned on the comic but not on the TV show (as far as I remember).

> In the early stages of the outbreak, Michonne runs on foot to her
> house. This attracts a street full of zombies to follow her. While she
> arrives home, she meets her boyfriend, Mike and his brave but idiotic
> best friend, Terry. A zombie tries to break in but Mike kills it. In
> the process, Mike becomes bitten. At that time, Michonne bandages
> Mike, who is unaware that he is infected. That night, Michonne
> searches a neighbor's house for supplies and discovers her trademark
> sword. She gets pinned down in the house during the night and returns
> home the next day, finding that both Mike and Terry have become
> walkers. She manages to survive their attack and lock them away.
>
> Her
> noisy encounter causes her street to become overrun. Michonne becomes
> trapped and runs out of food. She notices walkers don't attack one
> another and hacks off the arms and lower jaws of Mike and Terry. She
> chains them up by their necks to use them as escorts for an escape
> that was successful. Michonne says her final words to the zombified
> Mike and Terry, to help remember who they are, and because she has no
> one to talk to.

[Michonne on Walking Dead Wiki](http://walkingdead.wikia.com/wiki/Michonne_%28Comic_Series%29)

Here's an image I found with Michonne fighting off the two of them:
[image]

From the show (S04E09), we see that the boyfriend and his friend are named Mike and Terry respectively.

Comment: That was somewhat cryptically alluded to in one of the past 2 episodes, when she had a "flashback/dream sequence" to being in her kitchen with the 2 men.  She was cooking and the men were sitting around a table, and she started chopping vegetables or something with her Kitana.  Suddenly, they looked like walkers and had no arms.